# Car wont take gas

Tags: fuel-tank

When I go to gas station and take gas cap off, i feel and hear pressure towards gas cap. Then when i go to putting gas in my car, withing 30 cents of pumping, gas is overflowing. So what i been doing was when it starts to overflow, i put gas cap back on then turn car on then press gas pedal a little bit, then turn car back off. The little overflow would be gone. So ill pump a little more gas in until it does the same thing. Its a repeated cycle until after like the 3rd time of doing it then car would take gas

Comment: Here's an example https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4AEFabYI1Do

Comment: What's the car?  Ford (trucks anyway) have a regular issue with the carbon canister on the end of the vent for the gas tank getting clogged over the years with road crap (apparently). This prevents the tank from venting quickly when you pump.  Some folks replace the canister, others do more mischievous things.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sometimes the angle at which you hold the gas nozzle will help it accept fuel easier. I have to do this on my truck (hold the nozzle at about the 11 o'clock position).

Comment: Make and model?